# Typescript complains in class generic type using an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic class so defined:

```
class Store<T extends Record<string, string | number | boolean>> {...}
```

When I instantiate it, Typescript complains with the message `"Type 'Test1' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, string | number | boolean>'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Test1'."`

```
interface Test1 {
    name: string;
    year: number;
    retired: boolean;
}

const store = new Store<Test1>();
```

Instead if I use a type alias everything compiles perfectly:

```
type Test2 = {
    name: string;
    year: number;
    retired: boolean;
};

const store = new Store<Test2>();
```

I have read various answers here about Type vs. Interface but here seems going backward.
Could you enlighten me?
mario